# Как сделать чтобы скрипт работал постоянно при нажатии?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы чтобы работало постоянно и не надо было перезагружать страницу, например если я нажал 100 раз на кнопку, то надо чтобы скрипт тоже сработал 100 раз?

```js
    var x = document.getElementById('reverse');
    document.getElementById('new-wrapper').style.display = 'none';



    x.onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('wrapper').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('new-wrapper').style.display = 'block';
    

    x.onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('wrapper').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('new-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = document.getElementById('reverse');
    document.getElementById('new-wrapper').style.display = 'none';

x.onclick = function() {
  toggleStyle(document.getElementById('wrapper'));
  toggleStyle(document.getElementById('new-wrapper'))
}

function toggleStyle(el) {
  el.style.display = el.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none ';
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">111</div>
<div id="new-wrapper">222</div>
<input type="button" id="reverse" value="reverse"/>
```

Comment: а как сделать чтобы это происходило с медленным уменьшением прозрачнсти, если так можно?

Comment: Можно, но анимация и вообще, всё что касается UI - это не ко мне. :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = document.getElementById('reverse');

const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
const newWrapper = document.getElementById('new-wrapper');

x.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);

function toggle() {
  wrapper.classList.toggle('hide');
  newWrapper.classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#new-wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">Wrapper</div>
<div id="new-wrapper" class="hide">New wrapper</div>

<button id="reverse">Toggle</button>
```